# Deletion using Linked List Queues in OCAML

Tags: linked-list, queue, ocaml, option-type

I'm trying to implement a singly-linked list (queue) in OCAML which is very difficult and not as intuitive as I thought it would be. Let me first state the invariants of the queue that I am implementing:

```
q.head and q.tail are either both None, or
   - q.head and q.tail both point to Some nodes, and
     - q.tail is reachable by following 'next' pointers
       from q.head
     - q.tail's next pointer is None.
```

The queues and their associated nodes are declared as using options as follows:

```
type 'a qnode = { v: 'a;
                    mutable next: 'a qnode option }

  type 'a queue = { mutable head: 'a qnode option;
                    mutable tail: 'a qnode option }
```

I have many test cases but the one that fails first is this one:

```
let test (): bool = 
  let q = from_list [5; 6; 7] in
  delete 5 q;
  valid q && to_list q = [6; 7]
;; run_test "delete element from front of queue" test
```

Valid () just tests whether the queue satisfies the invariants. And here is my implementation:

```
let delete (elt: 'a) (q: 'a queue) : unit =
    if not (valid q) then failwith "delete: given invalid queue";
    let rec loop_delete (elt: 'a) (no: 'a qnode option) : unit = 
      begin match no with 
      |None -> ()
      |Some n -> (*Item to delete is only item in queue*)
               if n.v = elt && n.next = None then 
               (q.head <- None; q.tail <- None) 
               else if n.v = elt && n.next = Some n 
               then (q.head <- n.next; n.next <- None) else loop_delete elt n.next
      end
    in loop_delete elt q.head
```

Why is n.next not updating appropriately? Moreover, I'm sure there are many other issues wrong with my implementation. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

According to suggestions below, I've made the following adjustments. The comments indicate remaining confusions.

```
let delete (elt: 'a) (q: 'a queue) : unit =
    if not (valid q) then failwith "delete: given invalid queue";
    let rec loop_delete (elt: 'a) (prev: 'a qnode option) 
    (curr: 'a qnode option) : unit = 
      begin match prev, curr with 
      |_, None -> ()
      |None, Some n -> if n.v = elt && n.next = None then (q.head <- None; q.tail <- None) (*One element in list only...right??*)
      else if n.v = elt && n.next != None then (*How to continuously update prev and curr??* else ()
      |Some n, Some n1 -> (*??*)
      end
    in loop_delete elt None q.head
```

Comment: What’s the optional tag doing on your question? (`Optional` is an immutable type that may contain a value or reference.)

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry my earlier answer was wrong. I missed that you're using `q` directly in your helper function.)

Your function `loop_delete` looks for the matching node, but when it finds the matching node it seems to make unwarranted assumptions. If the matching node `n` is at the end of the queue (`n.next = None`), it assumes it was the only element of the queue (it sets `q.head` and `q.tail` to `None`). If the matching node isn't at the end of the queue, it seems to assume that the matching node was at the beginning of the queue (it sets `q.head` to `n.next`).

As a separate problem, this is not a reasonable test:

```
n.next = Some n
```

What it tests is whether the `next` pointer of `n` points to `n` itself. If you just want to know whether `n.next` points to any node you could say `n.next <> None`.

As an even more general comment, when deleting from a singly linked list you generally need to keep track of two nodes, the node you're interested in and the previous node in the list. When you find the node you want to delete, you need to change the `next` value of the previous node.

You shouldn't really need to think about pointers when coding in OCaml, but it's not too wrong to think of `None` as a null pointer and `Some n` as a pointer to the node `n`. For the first call you don't have a previous node, so the call might look like this:

```
loop_delete elt None q.head
```

When you want to move to the next node inside `loop_delete`, the call might look something like this:

```
loop_delete elt no n.next
```

In essence you are passing two values of type `'a qnode option`. They represent the previous node and the current node. If there's no previous node it's because you're at the beginning of the list. If there's no current node it's because you're at the end of the list.

Sorry for unhelpful comments earlier. Maybe this is a little better.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean regarding modifying q.head as I'm only modifying the queue itself via the Some and None options that are functioning as pointers (the nodes in qnode). The point of `loop_delete elt q.head ` is so that any queue passed in would automatically begin at the head by virtue of the  inner recursive function call. As per your suggestion of using sentinel nodes. Can you propose a method of implementing that? Would that address the original issue?

Comment: That's a little bit more helpful. My next question is how to keep track of previous and current nodes with the current interface since there's no such things as pointers per say. Should I declare a new qnode but leave the val field undefined and use that as a pointer?

Comment: I will add some more suggestions to my answer.

Comment: Your suggestions make sense but there are two problems. 1) I do not know how to distinguish between whether the element I want to delete is the only element in the list vs whether the element I want to delete is the last element in the list. 2) I do not know how to continuously update the previous node pointer or the "None" in the first call to `loop_delete elt None q.head`. It's times like these that Ocaml feels not very intuitive/useful

Comment: If the element is the only one in the list, the previous pointer and its `next` field will both be None. To update the pointers as you call `loop_delete`, you can use the code I showed. FWIW, this kind of OCaml code is virtually identical to code in any language with pointers. (Furthermore it's not particularly idiomatic OCaml code.)

Comment: I take back what I said earlier about the difficulty of Ocaml with this particular data structure. Having got it down, in my opinion it's actually more simple and elegant to implement doubly linked lists than it is using other OO programming languages.